# How to use the aws-sdk-java JmesParser to filter JSON

Tags: java, aws-java-sdk, jmespath, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I am attempting to use the Java JmesParser provided by the aws-sdk-java (I have tried v1 and now v2).

Using the test data from the JmesPath website, I am using the following JSON as my `inputValue`:

```
{
  "locations": [
    {"name": "Seattle", "state": "WA"},
    {"name": "New York", "state": "NY"},
    {"name": "Bellevue", "state": "WA"},
    {"name": "Olympia", "state": "WA"}
  ]
}
```

and the following String as my JMESPath `expression`:

```
locations[?state == 'WA'].name
```

I then have the following Java:

```
Expression expression = JmesPathParser.parse(expression);
JmesPathAcceptorGenerator generator = new JmesPathAcceptorGenerator(ClassName.get(model.getMetadata().getFullWaitersInternalPackageName(),
            WaitersRuntimeGeneratorTask.RUNTIME_CLASS_NAME));
generator.interpret(expression, inputValue);
```

The last line returns the following:

```
{
  "locations": [
    {"name": "Seattle", "state": "WA"},
    {"name": "New York", "state": "NY"},
    {"name": "Bellevue", "state": "WA"},
    {"name": "Olympia", "state": "WA"}
  ]
}.field("locations").filter(x0 -> x0.field("state").compare("==", x0.constant("WA"))).field("name")
```

I'm assuming it's the added `.field()` section that I need to somehow evaluate to return the result, but I can't seem to find any way to do it. How do I get it to actually run the filter against my JSON and return a result?

Comment: Are you sure those are not internal implementation details? Those classes you're using don't seem to be a documented part of the SDK.